# The CDF of a summation of random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I have the following random variable $Y=\sum\limits_{k=1}^KX_k$, where $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^K$ are independent and identically distributed random variables. The CDF of $X_k$ is give by $F_X(x)=1-\frac{1}{x+1}$. How can I find an expression for the CDF of Y?

Thanks

Comment: So... the $X_k$'s take values in $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Re the rejected edit: one needs 50 points to comment, except on ones own posts and answer to ones questions.